# TinyMCE control not showing in Umbraco (Chrome only)

Tags: c#, google-chrome, tinymce, umbraco

The TinyMCE control for RichTextEditor properties in the Umbraco back-office do not show in Chrome, but are visible in other browsers. The text editor box is just missing entirely.

The Chrome console shows the error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

on the page `tinymceCompress.aspx`

Looking into the source of this file in Chrome Dev Tools, the HTML output for an ASP.NET error page is being appended to the end of the file. The error is:

```
Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent.
```

I have manually read the reponse to the `tinymceCompress.aspx` in Fiddler for both Chrome (not working) and IE (working), and the reponse is exactly the same. There is no ASP.NET error message appended to the bottom of either response.

The control used to show in all browers, it is only recently that it appears to have broken. To our knowledge, we have not modified the Umbraco install.

This is Umbraco 4.11.9.

Comment: Any luck with this? Curious if you ever found the problem.

Comment: It turned out to be that we were modifying the header somewhere else in the code, so this was a genuine error. What is confusing is that it only appeared on Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't found the answer yet, try looking in the Tiny MCE javascript files. I recall a while ago running into a file which was in the Umbraco release which had a misplaced SCM merge snippet (looks something like <<<). I think it may have been a similar issue.

EDIT: To add to this, you may be able to do a text search across all the scripts that are loaded and look for something like this:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
```

or

```
>>>>>>> branch_name (as an example)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue in upgrading Umbraco v4.5.2 to v4.11.9. If you upgrade it from v4.5.2 to v4.11.10 the issue won't happen in Chrome any more.